# php random message fade to next random message in 20 seconds

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, random

I have a webpage with a small illustrated cloud and inside of is there is a small message
which appears randomly from a mySql table containing 30 messages

It works perfectly

code:

```
 $select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `cloudbig` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
```

If page is refreshed another message appears

My client want´s to... if user is on that page the cloud to change to another
random message each 20 sec and with a smooth fade effect

Any idea of how I would the script - Isn´t it just something like
" + 20 second GET NEXT record ORDER BY RAND ()" ... and some javascript script
for the fade?

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP and MySQL.  This is a JavaScript question.

Answer (score 2):

You could fetch a bunch of messages from the database, echo them into a Javascript array and write/find a javascript that cycles them with an effect (you could use jQuery for the fading). This is a 'cache' type of approach.

If the table's content changes rapidly, or if a fixed-size pool per visit is unacceptable for another reason, you could make asynchronous requests to the server using AJAX. This way you can get new messages dynamically from the server. This is probably not necessary though, I'd recommend the above approach.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least three different ways to approach this.

One is to list all of the messages where you want them to go and have only one of them visible.  In JavaScript you can then cycle through them with a timeout.

Another possibility is to only show one message and then fetch the next message via AJAX after a timeout.

A hybrid of the two would be to not show any messages at first, but then have your JavaScript fetch all of the messages via AJAX once the document finishes loading and load them into an array client-side.  Then you can just cycle through them using a timeout.  This would be my preferred way, but it is up to you.